# Does Heroku connect supports Chatter in salesforce?

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

when i tried to integrate chatter ,there is error

> The object is read only and does not support writing to salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @Priyanka Belurkar

You will need to use the chatter api: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_what_is_chatter_connect.htm

Here you have some slides on how to use chatter outside Salesforce with heroku:
https://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/chatter-everywhere-externalizing-chatter-with-heroku-and-the-chatter-rest-ap-is-v3